# How to get more than 100 query results with SQL on portal.azure.com Cosmos DB Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

On https://portal.azure.com/ - Cosmos DB Data Explorer, I can execute SQL queries. The result output is 100:

```
SELECT c.email FROM Clients c
```

[image: screenshot]

To reduce the number of network round trips required to retrieve all applicable results, you can increase the page size using `x-ms-max-item-count` request header to up to 1000: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips

Is it possible to use `x-ms-max-item-count` on that SQL query? Any other way to increase the limit of output results to it maximum?

Related question: [How to get more than 100 query results with Azure DocumentDB REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600008/how-to-get-more-than-100-query-results-with-azure-documentdb-rest-api)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact, there is a `Query Explorer` in azure cosmos db portal which is similar to `Data Explorer` mentioned in your question.

[image]

As you see,you could set items per page as custom number or unlimited. If it is in REST API, you could follow the case to configure the `x-ms-max-item-count` header. It it is in SDK,you could set the [MaxItemCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxitemcount) property in FeedOptions.

Comment: Thanks... Hopefully that warning (_This blade will be retired soon. Please use Data Explorer going forward_) will be there long time!

Comment: @chelder Haha... i believe the page size setting will also be transplanted into data explorer.

Comment: It is a shame that there are no decent tools for Azure Cosmos DB. Most things rely on you using the SDK.

Comment: This does not exist any more

Answer (score 11):

There's a setting blade in the upper right corner of the *Data Explorer*:

[image]

There you can specify the **Page Options**: *Query results per page*

[image]

Comment: The old accepted answer is not longer the latest Azure version, this is the current correct answer for now

Comment: Yes, Unlimited option doesn't work for me. I have to choose Custom option and provide a huge number of results in the page.