# Max item count in Cosmos DB trigger

Tags: triggers, azure-cosmosdb

I'm creating a pre-trigger for a Cosmos DB container. The pre-trigger is supposed to fetch all data related to the triggering document id. The `incoming_document.items` is always returning 100 when there are more than 100 documents expected (which seems to be limited by the query). I tried to set the `pageSize` property to -1 in the FeedOptions parameters and to use continuation, but it is still giving me 100. How can I fix this to give the total count?

Here is a simplified version of the code (without the continuation, I used a similar code to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#async-promises)):

```
function trgAddStats() {
    var context = getContext();
    var request = context.getRequest();
    var incoming_document = request.getBody();

    var container = context.getCollection();
    var incoming_document.items = 1;
    var filterQuery = {
        "query": `SELECT t.customer, t.amount FROM Transactions_ds t WHERE t.customer = @customer`,
        "parameters": [{
                "name": "@customer",
                "value": incoming_document.customer
            }
        ]
    };
    var isAccepted = container.queryDocuments(container.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, {},
        function (err, items, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);
            incoming_document.items += items.length;    
            request.setBody(incoming_document);
        }
    );

    if (!isAccepted) throw "Unable to update transaction, abort";
}
```

Comment: You should set the `maxItemCount` in the feedoptions.

Answer (score 0):

- For getting more than `100` documents in Cosmos DB we can make use of **x-ms-max-item-count**.
- The maximum number of values that can be returned by the query execution is done by the **x-ms-max-item-count** header.
- The default value of the query results is `100` and it can be configured from `1–1000` using this header.
- For more details regarding Pagination of query results in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#pagination-of-query-results).
- You can Customize the number for Items per page in Query Explorer too like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59167733/18230038).

Comment: Someone mentioned `maxItemCount` in a comment the other day. Note that the OP is using an SDK, not a raw REST call, so the comment under the question covers it (and there's no need to talk about headers, since this is about SDK use). Aside from that: Please don't just copy content from documentation, as an answer (it's not an answer - it's just sharing some docs). At best, you should just share the doc link as a comment under the question.